# OpenVPN client stops working after a few minutes

Tags: openvpn, arch-linux

I'm using OpenVPN client, and it works fine but after a few minutes the VPN stops working.

I'm getting these errors in the logs:

```
Sun May 10 20:55:28 2015 [nrt-c01.ipvanish.com] Inactivity timeout (--ping-restart), restarting
Sun May 10 20:55:28 2015 SIGUSR1[soft,ping-restart] received, process restarting
Sun May 10 20:55:28 2015 Restart pause, 2 second(s)
Sun May 10 20:55:30 2015 Socket Buffers: R=[163840->327680] S=[163840->131072]
Sun May 10 20:55:30 2015 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]110.50.241.72:443
Sun May 10 20:55:30 2015 UDPv4 link local: [undef]
Sun May 10 20:55:30 2015 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]110.50.241.72:443
Sun May 10 20:56:10 2015 [UNDEF] Inactivity timeout (--ping-restart), restarting
Sun May 10 20:56:10 2015 SIGUSR1[soft,ping-restart] received, process restarting
Sun May 10 20:56:10 2015 Restart pause, 2 second(s)
Sun May 10 20:56:12 2015 Socket Buffers: R=[163840->327680] S=[163840->131072]
Sun May 10 20:56:12 2015 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]110.50.241.72:443
Sun May 10 20:56:12 2015 UDPv4 link local: [undef]
Sun May 10 20:56:12 2015 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]110.50.241.72:443
Sun May 10 20:56:52 2015 [UNDEF] Inactivity timeout (--ping-restart), restarting
Sun May 10 20:56:52 2015 SIGUSR1[soft,ping-restart] received, process restarting
Sun May 10 20:56:52 2015 Restart pause, 2 second(s)
Sun May 10 20:56:54 2015 Socket Buffers: R=[163840->327680] S=[163840->131072]
Sun May 10 20:56:54 2015 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]110.50.241.72:443
Sun May 10 20:56:54 2015 UDPv4 link local: [undef]
Sun May 10 20:56:54 2015 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]110.50.241.72:443
```

My configuration is the following, directly from the VPN provider:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote nrt-c01.ipvanish.com 443
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
persist-remote-ip
ca ca.ipvanish.com.crt
tls-remote nrt-c01.ipvanish.com
auth-user-pass /etc/openvpn/ipvanish.user
comp-lzo
verb 3
auth SHA256
cipher AES-256-CBC
keysize 256
tls-cipher DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:AES256-SHA
```

What could cause that? I'm using Arch Linux on a Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have **keepalive** enabled. Ask your VPN provider to add:

keepalive 10 900

to the servers config file.

Comment: the keepalive directive can be used on both server and client - so he could just as well add the directive to his own config